# How to access global variable inside the class in python

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to access the index variable. When I press play button the index is printed but when pressing previous and next button I got the below error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'index' referenced before assignment.

How to use the global variable inside the class?

Example code:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class KivyGalleryApp(App):
    def build(self):
        class Musicscreens(Screen):
            def __init__(self, **kwargs):
                super(Musicscreens, self).__init__(**kwargs)
                index=0
                def Previous(self):
                    #global index
                    index=index-1
                    print (index)
                def play(self):
                    #global index
                    print (index)
                def next_index(self):
                    #global index
                    index=index+1
                    print (index)
                box1=BoxLayout()
                prev_button=Button(text='Previous')
                prev_button.bind(on_press=Previous)    
                play_button=Button(text='play')
                play_button.bind(on_press=play)
                next_button=Button(text='next')
                next_button.bind(on_press=next_index)  
                box1.add_widget(prev_button)
                box1.add_widget(play_button)
                box1.add_widget(next_button)
                self.add_widget(box1)

        sm=ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Musicscreens(name='sample'))
        return sm

KivyGalleryApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using object-oriented programming, you can simply make `index` an instance attribute and each callback an instance method:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Musicscreens(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Musicscreens, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.index = 0

        prev_button = Button(text='Previous')
        prev_button.bind(on_press=self.previous)

        play_button = Button(text='play')
        play_button.bind(on_press=self.play)

        next_button = Button(text='next')
        next_button.bind(on_press=self.next_index)

        box1 = BoxLayout()
        box1.add_widget(prev_button)
        box1.add_widget(play_button)
        box1.add_widget(next_button)

        self.add_widget(box1)

    def previous(self, instance):
        self.index -= 1
        print(self.index)

    def play(self, instance):
        print(self.index)

    def next_index(self, instance):
        self.index += 1
        print(self.index)


class KivyGalleryApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Musicscreens(name='sample'))
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    KivyGalleryApp().run()
```